# Storing data with JavaScript in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

I am trying to create a simple app that allows users to select the dev who they are pairing with on that day and then a set a timer so they switch.
Currently, I am storing all the information in Firebase, but that seems like overkill.

Is there a way I can store data in the browser with JavaScript, such as in a cookie? The info I would need to store would be a small object like so:

```
obj1 = { name: 'rob', pairName: 'chris', timeLeft: 15 }
```

Or does Firebase make more sense?

I need it to persist, so that if I refresh, it does not 'reset' the data.

I am not asking how to do it, just advice and the ideal path :)

Comment: Maybe [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) might be helpful (if the browsers being used support it)?

Comment: does chris need to know that rob has chosen him? just be sure if you move away from something centralized that it doesn't come back to bite you

Comment: Yes, modern browsers offer like three of four places to store information. But in general they're simple key/value storages where everything has to be serialized as string. (Said that, we have JSON anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

try this! =)

```
var DB = function(){
    this.Read = function(index){
        if(this.Test()){
            return JSON.parse(localStorage[index]).data;
        }
    },
    this.Write = function(index, data){
        localStorage[index] = JSON.stringify({data : data});
    }
    this.Test = function(){
        return typeof localStorage == typeof {};
    }
}

// example:
var x = new DB(); // new data base
x.Write('food', ['food','bar','google']); // write data
console.log(x.Read('food')); // get data!
```